# PreferenceActivity lifecycle

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PreferenceActivity lifecycle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5035000/preferenceactivity-lifecycle)

I read http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html
but I have a question about PreferenceActivity lifecycle:

Does a PreferenceActivity get onStop() or onDestroy() call?

I understand it gets onStop() called when user clicks 'Back', but what about onDestroy()?
when does onDestory() for PreferenceActivity get called?

Thank you.